# SQL Count: erratic behaviour

Tags: sql, count, mariadb, relational-database

A piece of SQL that I have written is not behaving as intended. A vital piece of logic involves counting how many guests are VIPs, but the SQL seems to consistently get an incorrect answer.

The following database has 6 guests, 3 of whom are VIPs.

```
CREATE TABLE `guest` (
  `GuestID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `fullname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vip` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `guest`
--

INSERT INTO `guest` (`GuestID`, `fullname`, `vip`) VALUES
(912, 'Sam',  0),
(321, 'Sev', 0),
(629, 'Joe', 0),
(103, 'Tom', 1),
(331, 'Cao', 1),
(526, 'Conor', 1);
```

Initially the SQL returned a value saying that there were 5 VIPs, which is incorrect as there are only 3 VIPs. This is quite a complicated database, and in generating a minimum viable example for the sake of this question (with a reproducible error) the script now states that there are only 2 VIPs. Again, this is incorrect.

The SQL in question is

```
SELECT slotguest.FK_SlotNo, Count(CASE WHEN guest.vip = 1 THEN 1 END) AS guest_count 
FROM guest 
INNER JOIN slotguest ON guest.GuestID = slotguest.FK_guest 
GROUP BY slotguest.FK_SlotNo;
```

The slotguest structure and content is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE `slotguest` (
  `FK_SlotNo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FK_guest` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `slotguest`
--

INSERT INTO `slotguest` (`FK_SlotNo`, `FK_guest`) VALUES
(396, 912),
(396, 321),
(396, 629),
(396, 103),
(396, 331),
(396, 526);
```

What is causing Count to come up with a consistently incorrect answer?

Comment: Works for me. It shows a count of `3`. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vbA9HaDA456UaQEDhzGfuv/0

Comment: Try to change `Count(CASE WHEN guest.vip = 1 THEN 1 END)` for `Sum(CASE WHEN guest.vip = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: Tested on Maria DB. Works for me.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=4bd80eb2b76961e351beeaadbe29d597

Comment: Your query does not return "how many guests are VIPs". Here you are lucky people can guess what you mean. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. PS Create a [mre] before you consider posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As identicated in the comments (check from users @Fábio Amorim, @Rajat), your query seems to work as intended. Since, you set a value with the `CASE WHEN`, it might be better to use `SUM`.

It might be more visible if you bring the counts for the different VIP categories to find where there might be a leakage of data.

```
SELECT guest.vip, slotguest.FK_SlotNo, COUNT(*) AS guest_per_category
FROM guest 
INNER JOIN slotguest ON guest.GuestID = slotguest.FK_guest
GROUP BY guest.vip,slotguest.FK_SlotNo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Smells like "explode-implode".  Given

```
SELECT ... COUNT(*)
    FROM a JOIN b ...
    GROUP BY ...
```

The query is performed thus:

1. `JOIN` the tables.  Assuming the tables are not trivially 1:1, this leads to more rows than either of the tables.
2. Do aggregates (such as `COUNT`) against that temp table.
3. Only then does the `GROUP BY` shrink back to the originally desired number of rows.

The solution is to avoid doing aggregates with more than the one table that contains the data being counted/summed.  Sometimes the pattern is

```
 SELECT ...
     FROM ( SELECT x, COUNT(*) AS ct FROM a GROUP BY x ) AS b
     JOIN c ON ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To explain what's wrong, and give an answer closer to the O.P.'s query ...

(I assume the O.P. is a cut-down example of what's going wrong, and the actual query is more complex. If we knew the bigger picture, I suspect I wouldn't code it like that.)

In the O.P. query, `CASE WHEN guest.vip = 1 THEN 1 END` is ill-formed. That's a conditional expression; it should return a specific value for all rows retrieved by the query -- that is for rows where `guest.vip <> 1`.

As it is, behaviour is undefined; it produces the expected answer on some DBMS's, as the comments are telling; it doesn't on others, as per the O.P. I guess for those it is producing the expected answer, the DBMS is treating the `CASE` as returning `Null`, then the `Count( )` is ignoring Nulls. This is one of the more horrible consequences of `Null` in SQL.

So as per @Fábio Amorim's comment, the `CASE` needs an `ELSE`, consequently `Count( )` gives an unhelpful result, so get the `ELSE` to return `0` and `Sum( )` the `1` or `0`:

```
SELECT slotguest.FK_SlotNo, Sum(CASE WHEN guest.vip = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS guest_count 
FROM guest 
INNER JOIN slotguest ON guest.GuestID = slotguest.FK_guest 
GROUP BY slotguest.FK_SlotNo;
```